# How to compute a 3d miniature model from a large set of 3d geometric models

Tags: graphics, computer-vision, rendering, computational-geometry

i want to import a set of 3d geometries in to current scene, the imported geometries contains tons of basic componant which may represent an 
entire building. The Product Manager want the entire building to be displayed 
as a 3d miniature(colors and textures must corrosponding to the original building).

The problem:  Is there any algortithms which can handle these large amount of datasin a reasonable time and memory cost.
              //worst case: there may be  a billion triangle surfaces in the imported data

And, by the way, i am considering another solotion: using a type of textue mapping: 
1 take enough snapshots by the software render of the imported objects. 
2 apply the images to a surface .
3 use some shader tricks to perform effects like bump-mapping---when the view posisition  changed, the texture will alter and makes the viewer feels as if he was looking at a 3d scene.

----my modeller and render are ACIS and hoops, any ideas?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but fixing all the typos would make it more attractive.

Comment: Feasibility depends on the capabilities of your modeling/rendering engine. Can you tell more ?

Comment: modeling/rendering is ACIS and hoops

Answer (score 0):

An option is to generate side views of the building at a suitable resolution, using the rendering engine and map them as textures to a parallelipipoid.

The next level of refinement is to obtain a bump or elevation map that you can use for embossing. Not the easiest to do.

If the modeler allows it, you can slice the volume using a 2D grid of "voxels" (actually prisms). You can do that by repeatedly cutting the model in two with a plane. And in every prism, find the vertex closest to the observer. This will give you a 2D map of elevations, with the desired resolution.

Alternatively, intersect parallel "rays" (linear objects) with the solid and keep the first endpoint.

It can also be that your modeler includes a true voxel model, or that rendering can be zone with a Z-buffer that you can access.

Comment: this is just what i want, but i need more detail steps to complish the mission, is there any materials like demo, papers or books which i can refered to. and view the effect before i implement it. by the way, thank you sir...

Comment: I am afraid this is highly dependent on the specifics of the tools you use; you need to dig the documentation. And there are papers on model simplification but I doubt they will be of much use to you as they won't provide the ready-made solutions you are dreaming of. (And you will probably find nothing about the approach I suggested, an unusual diversion of the Z-buffer.)

Comment: tools currently used: